# Python ngrok: Sending fatal alert BadCertificate

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ngrok, pyngrok

I am trying to do a simple ngrok tunnel in python but I am getting this error consistently. I cant find anything related to this with my Google searches. The code worked fine on my Mac and regular Raspberry Pi, but when I try to run it on a headless RPi with Raspbian Lite (no GUI) it gives me the following error:

```
Sending fatal alert BadCertificate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/AutoARISS/web.py", line 78, in <module>
    tunnel = ngrok.connect(port, authtoken_from_env=True)
  File "ngrok_wrapper", line 16, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "ngrok_wrapper", line 7, in wrap
ValueError: ('failed to connect session', 'tls handshake error')
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Please provide the code you are using that generates this error, along with additional details about your environment and configuration.